# "code":155, "message":"This application has exceeded its request limit

Tags: ios, parse-platform

We are receiving the following error: **"code":155,"message":"This application has exceeded its request limit**, although in the parse.com dashboard - request limit graph we are not even close to exceed our limit.

In the same time we are started to experience many crashes in our iOS app today.
Both app and parse.com code was not changed for more than a month, so the chances that there are problems in our code are very low.

Please help!

Comment: Are you exceeding the requests *per second* limit? By default, that's 30.

Comment: I'm not. I pay for 50 requests per seconds, and I rarely get to 40. @AdamWright